# Is FBE + Metadata Encryption secure if pin/password not set

Tags: file-system, encryption, android-11, aosp

My device is based on Android 11 and does not have a security lock screen. By default it has FBE and Metadata encryption enabled. How secure this encryption is without setting the Pin/password.
How is the default key generated.

Can anyone share any commit details which gives us the key generation and storage mechanisms on AOSP

Comment: Secure against what? If you can simply boot the phone and look at all data the app shows I would call this not secure. If no lockscreen password has been set then a default password is used, which is well-known.

Comment: Hey Robert, Thanks for the comment, I want to understand the Key generation process when the password or pin is not set. I read a few posts and found that the the FBE keys are linked to screen lock (Ref: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/196230/connection-between-pin-password-and-encryption-keys-in-android/247954#247954), So how does the key generation happen, and where are they stored. please share the commits on AOSP if possible

Comment: The linked answer shows as far as I know the complete process. As I wrote if you don't set a password a static default password will be used. Besides that nothing changes.

Comment: Note that the default password is usually [default_password](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22default_password%22) (with underscore).